# Swift: I'm super confused! UIGravityBehavior vs NSTimer vs CGPointMake on UILabel

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift, ios8

So I declared a UILabel! named "textLabel" which has a gravity effect which goes up. Now, When it reachs -30, I want the label to reappear at (200, 444). I used a NSTimer to check if (labelText > -30) but when it reaches/passes that point, it just flashes where it's suppose to appear (around the middle) but it does not start from the middle. here is most of my code.

How do I make the Label appear at it's new position? so it can just cycle again once it reaches that -30 on the y-axis?? I've searched and searched. HELPPPPPPP

```
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
var itemBehavior: UIDynamicItemBehavior!

var boundaryTimer = NSTimer()

Override func viewDidLoad() {
    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: view)
    gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [textLabel])
    animator.addBehavior(gravity)

    boundaryTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "leftBoundary", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    itemBehavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [textLabel])
    itemBehavior.elasticity = 1.2
    gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0.0 , -0.01)
    animator.addBehavior(itemBehavior)
}

func leftBoundary() {
    if textLabel.center.y < 40 {

        self.textLabel.center = CGPointMake(200, 444)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting the `center`, you can add and then remove an attachment behavior, e.g.:

```
func leftBoundary() {
    if textLabel.center.y < 40 {
        let attachment = UIAttachmentBehavior(item: textLabel, attachedToAnchor: textLabel.center)
        animator.addBehavior(attachment)
        attachment.anchorPoint = view.center
        attachment.action = {[unowned self, attachment] in
            if self.textLabel.center.y > 100 {
                self.animator.removeBehavior(attachment)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, you might want to change the `itemBehavior` so that `allowRotation` is `false` (depending upon your desired UI).

Also note, this `action` that I use here is something you could use with your `gravity` behavior, too. So, rather than a timer (which might not always catch the label at the same time), use an `action`, which is called upon every frame of the animation.

Comment: Rob-This worked! It does appear in the middle of the screen (view.center) how do I make it appear at the bottom though? I've tried a few things but to no avail. ps. I'm new to swift. thank you in advance as well.

Comment: Rather than setting the `anchorPoint` to `view.center`, set it to some other value (e.g., use `CGPointMake`).

Answer (score 0):

You should first remove all label behaviors from the animator.

This has to do with how UIKit Dynamics works. It really only manipulates the layer / presentation layer of your view, so you need to reset everything if you want to set the position yourself (via the view, which also affects the layer).

Also, I think the setup with the timer is not very efficient. Rather, you should give KVO (key-value observing) a try. You can observe the key path "center.y" and react if it passes your limit.